# Mysql select statement is too slow. How to make it faster?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using this MySQL query to select a value that is not in another table, I have more than 50000 records in the second table and this query is too slow how can I make it master

```
SELECT t1.subcategory, t1.category, t1.shortname
FROM test_list t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM (
        SELECT category,subcategory,count(*) 
        FROM bill_master t2
        WHERE t2.pid = '18398'
        group by category,subcategory
    ) t2
    WHERE t2.subcategory = t1.subcategory
    AND t2.category = t1.category
)
```

Comment: What is the `select 1 from()...` query for?  Can't you just use HAVING there?  Not sure that would make it quicker...  and why do you need count(*) in a subquery that never gets returned?  removing that might make it quicker.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what the query is supposed to be doing.

Comment: There's no need to group the subquery, since you're just checking whether anything exists, not using the values.

Comment: define `too slow`....

Comment: `t2` needs a composite `INDEX(pid, category, subcategory)`

Answer (score 2):

I think there's loads of grouping and counting that's not useful for what you're actually achieving.

```
SELECT t1.subcategory, t1.category, t1.shortname
FROM test_list t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT category FROM bill_master t2
                WHERE t2.pid = '18398'
                AND t2.subcategory = t1.subcategory
                AND t2.category = t1.category)
```

Comment: There is no difference both queries take the same time

Answer (score 0):

Another path to test.

```
select t1.subcategory, t1.category, t1.shortname
from test_list t1
    left outer join bill_master t2
    on t2.subcategory = t1.subcategory
    and t2.category = t1.category
    and t2.pid = '18398'
where (t2.category is null)
```

Comment: it takes too much time, its three times slower than my qury

Comment: @SmartDeveloper then you need some indexes.